# Second click on floating button with image (example: Add to favorite)

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, floating-action-button

First click: image on floating button will turn into filled red and submit data to Firebase.

Second click: image on floating button will turn back into just border and will delete the item from Firebase.

But appears to be my second click to remove item from Firebase is not working by any chance.

```
btnLove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        boolean showingFirst;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(showingFirst == true){
                btnLove.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav_filled_50);
                showingFirst = false;

                fav =  new Favorites(Common.currentUser.getPhone(),
                        drinkId,
                        currentDrink.getName(),
                        currentDrink.getImage(),
                        currentDrink.getPrice()
                        );
                favorites.child(Common.currentUser.getPhone()).child(drinkId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if(dataSnapshot.child(Common.currentUser.getPhone()).exists())
                        {
                            favorites.child(Common.currentUser.getPhone()).child(drinkId).removeValue();
                            favorites.child(Common.currentUser.getPhone()).child(drinkId).setValue(fav);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            favorites.child(Common.currentUser.getPhone()).child(drinkId).setValue(fav);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });


            } else {
                btnLove.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav_border_50);
                btnLove.setTag(70);
                showingFirst = true;
                favorites.child(Common.currentUser.getPhone()).child(drinkId).removeValue();

            }


        }
    });
```

Comment: is it entering the `else`?

Comment: Dear sire, else is when user click on second time and icon turn back to showingFirst = true. Here is when, item be remove supposedly

Comment: its not entering the else statement since showingfirst is always equal to true, `onclicklistener` showingfirst=true, then it enters the if and showingfirst is equal to false. in another click it enters the `onclicklistener` again and showingfirst is equal to true again.. so its not entering the else statement

Comment: Dear sir, thanks for the explaination. I've edited my code above, but it not deleting item from Firebase

Comment: just create another button

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
boolean showingFirst = true;
```

form the setOnClickListener and put this into outside of setOnClickListener method. when u clicking the button showingFirst will be always true coz you just creating this.

Comment: Dear sir, thanks for the explaination. I've edited my code above, but it not deleting item from Firebase

Comment: please stop creating "showingFirst" inside onclick method.